# How to remove inexistent referred document in mongodb ODM

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

Kinda new to mongodb. I know mongodb does not have constraints on references. So if I have an inexistent referred document, how can I remove it?

For example:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("51619a758ead0e6765000004"),
    createdAt: ISODate("2013-04-08T00:10:29+08:00"),
    works: [ { $ref: "products", $id: ObjectId("51619a758ead0e6765000007"), $db: "ihome", type: "product" } ]
}
```

The referred product has been removed. I don't know how to pull it from works? I tried below but not work:

```
$dm->createQueryBuilder('SupplierBundle:Supplier')
    ->update()
    ->field('id')->equals('51619a758ead0e6765000004')
    ->field('works.$id')->pull(new \MongoId('51619a758ead0e6765000007'))
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solve the bug where this happens and pull it manually, bro.

Comment: Yes, I'll definitely make this not happen. But it makes me tangled. I've already found how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I found how to do this:

```
$dm->createQueryBuilder('SupplierBundle:Supplier')
    ->update()
    ->field('id')->equals('51619a758ead0e6765000004')
    ->field('works')->pull(array('$id' => new \MongoId('51619a758ead0e6765000007')))
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Comment: And this does not matter whether the referred document exists or not